# Feature Engineering of mixed data type column

Tags: data-cleaning, feature-extraction

I have a data set in which I have to predict the price of a building. Among many features there is a feature called **Availability** which has two type values like :

```
"Ready To Move" and a date (e.g. "20-Jan", "18-May", etc.)
```

For example:

```
Availability           Price
------------           ----- 
Ready To Move           55
18-Apr                  38
```

How would you engineer this column to find its relationship with price and to draw other conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices. Among them try these:

- [Discretize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization_of_continuous_features) your target and use [chi-square association measure](http://uregina.ca/~gingrich/ch11a.pdf) or [Cramer's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) to see the association between variables.
- The other way around i.e. convert availability labels to numerics and simply try different association analysis methods like Correlation ([Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), [Spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient), [Kendall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient)) or [Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

PS: Please note that Spearman or Kendall Rank Correlations can also be applied to your categorical variables as they are ordered (dates).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with name "Number of days in which the building is going to be available" (Values will be (20-Jan / 18-Apr )-current date).